# bash: -q: command not found

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to install some software tool onto my Ubuntu 16.04 partition. The install script kinda breaks here:

```
getInstalledLegacyPXIRMPackage() {
    part=`$RPM -q $kLegacyPXIRMBaseName`
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo $part
        return
    fi
    echo ""
}
```

The error message I get is `bash: -q: command not found`.

This is part of an INSTALL file for a 32-bit version of labview 2012.

What is this error and what do I do to fix it?
Thanks!

Edit: Okay sorry, technically, it does not break at the func definition. It breaks when it is called here:

```
if [ "$(getInstalledLegacyPXIRMPackage)" != "" ] && [ "$(getIncludedPXIPSPackage)" == "" ]; then
.
.
.
fi
```

Comment: Think about what happens if the variable `RPM` is empty? (or if you tried to run a command like `$foo arg otherarg` with never having set `foo`)

Comment: Checking your code with [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) is a great start.

Comment: Also, Ubuntu, being derived from Debian, uses `apt` for its package management rather than `rpm` or `yum`.

Comment: Hmm, I hope the code you're really trying to run has normal spaces instead of the ones in this code block (I'm not sure what they are)

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to the variable `RPM` being empty or undefined at the time of executing the `getInstalledLegacyPXIRMPackage` function.

If `$RPM` is empty or undefined, the line

```
part=`$RPM -q $kLegacyPXIRMBaseName`
```

will be interpreted as an assignment of the result of the command `-q $kLegacyPXIRMBaseName`.

Make sure that you assign the proper value to `RPM` (and to `kLegacyPXIRMBaseName)`.